# iPhone X Face ID while on Enter Passcode screen

Tags: iphone, ios, face-id

Sometimes when I try to unlock my iPhone X with Face ID it fails and goes to the Enter Passcode screen. While on this screen what's the fastest way to get it to retry Face ID? I've found I can tap cancel and swipe up again, but hoping there's a faster way I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that tipping the phone away from you (i.e. bring it down to horizontal), and then bringing it back to face you again will cause Face ID to be tried again.